# Angular 2 - Kendo UI Calendar not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, calendar, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using the [Kendo-UI calendar for angular 2](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/calendar/)

However I'm having a problem where my calendar doesn't render correctly. I don't receive any errors whatsoever, this is how my calendar looks:

[image]

It creates an extremely large div (20.000 pixels) and only shows the weekdays in the correct place. When I scroll all the way down, it does render the months and days etc, like this:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to implement the calendar:

**vendor.ts**

```
import "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs";
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { CalendarModule } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs";
...
exports:[CalendarModule]
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
...
imports: [SharedModule2]
```

**mycomponent.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="showFromCalendar === true">
    <kendo-calendar></kendo-calendar>
</div>
```

It seems like I'm missing some file? I'm new to angular 2 and I'm not sure how to debug this since I don't receive any errors, so I hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like the calendar CSS is not loaded. Make sure you are using the latest version of the `@progress/kendo-theme-default` package, and that the included styles are registered on a global level without style encapsulation.

Comment: using `@import '~@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all';` my other kendo stuff works though.

Comment: I fixed it. We had the wrong theme file imported. They have a theme file for `@import '~@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all'`  I assume they use this for some of their angular 2 stuff. Thanks for getting me on the right path

Comment: Indeed, both packages are available, but the `@progress` one is most recent. The `@telerik` one is legacy and left for compatibility reasons. The whole Kendo UI for Angular completely behind the `@progress` scope.